# Single-signon with legacy system in Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

My application is providing RESTful WS.  In normal case, it will require user to logon before the user is allowed to call any business function.  This part is typical in Spring Security.

However, there is a legacy portal system we are going to integrate to provide SSO.  User may have been authenticated in the portal.  When user access our application through the portal, the portal is going to invoke a URL in our application with a token.  Our application will need to retrieve (from a DB, using stored proc) the user ID etc using that token.  Of course we will then need to find out the authorization in our application using that retrieved user ID.

My first thought is to have a new filter and add it to the springSecurityFilterChain filter chain, which will do the "authentication" base on the provided SSO token, and run before the normal authentication filter.  Is my direction correct? Where can I find some more information on how to add to the filter chain, and what is the default filter chain? My initial code turns on spring security by using `<sec:http>` tag, how easy it is to add such extra filter in chain?

May anyone give a hint on how to achieve this.  Thanks

Comment: I added info in my answer to suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new security realm:

```
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/legacy-app/**" realm="Legacy App" create-session="stateless" disable-url-rewriting="true"
      authentication-manager-ref="tokenAuthenticationManager" entry-point-ref="tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/legacy-app/**" access="hasAuthority('LEGACY_USER_ROLE')" />
    <custom-filter ref="tokenAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <logout logout-url="/legacy/logout" />
</http>
<authentication-manager id="tokenAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="tokenAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

```
<beans:bean id="tokenAuthenticationProvider" class="com.company.TokenAuthenticationProvider" >
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="tokenAuthenticationFilter" class="com.company.TokenAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="tokenAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.company.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
```

Here are the components:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!(userDetails instanceof User)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Missing or invalid authentication token");
        }
        User user = (User) userDetails;

        if (!getPasswordEncoder().isPasswordValid(user.getToken(), authentication.getCredentials().toString())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Missing or invalid authentication token");
        }

    }
}
```

Filter:

```
    public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest,?> authenticationDetailsSource = new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
        private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new NullRememberMeServices();
        private boolean ignoreFailure = true;
        private String credentialsCharset = "UTF-8";

        public TokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        }

        /**
         * Creates an instance which will authenticate against the supplied {@code AuthenticationManager}
         * and which will ignore failed authentication attempts, allowing the request to proceed down the filter chain.
         *
         * @param authenticationManager the bean to submit authentication requests to
         */
        public TokenAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
            ignoreFailure = true;
        }
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(this.authenticationManager, "An AuthenticationManager is required");

        if(!isIgnoreFailure()) {
            Assert.notNull(this.authenticationEntryPoint, "An AuthenticationEntryPoint is required");
        }
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final boolean debug = logger.isDebugEnabled();
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String header = request.getHeader("TOKEN");

        if (header == null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {

            String username = "LEGACY-USER";
            String authToken = header.trim();

            if (debug) {
                logger.debug("TOKEN found, proceeding with token authentication");
            }

            if (authenticationIsRequired(username)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("ID:" + username, authToken);
                authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
                Authentication authResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);

                if (debug) {
                    logger.debug("Authentication success: " + authResult);
                }

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

                rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authResult);

                onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
            }

        } catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

            if (debug) {
                logger.debug("Authentication request for failed: " + failed);
            }

            rememberMeServices.loginFail(request, response);

            onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);

            if (ignoreFailure) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, failed);
            }

            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }



    private boolean authenticationIsRequired(String username) {
        // Only reauthenticate if username doesn't match SecurityContextHolder and user isn't authenticated
        // (see SEC-53)
        Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if(existingAuth == null || !existingAuth.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Limit username comparison to providers which use usernames (ie UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)
        // (see SEC-348)

        if (existingAuth instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken && !existingAuth.getName().equals(username)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle unusual condition where an AnonymousAuthenticationToken is already present
        // This shouldn't happen very often, as BasicProcessingFitler is meant to be earlier in the filter
        // chain than AnonymousAuthenticationFilter. Nevertheless, presence of both an AnonymousAuthenticationToken
        // together with a BASIC authentication request header should indicate reauthentication using the
        // BASIC protocol is desirable. This behaviour is also consistent with that provided by form and digest,
        // both of which force re-authentication if the respective header is detected (and in doing so replace
        // any existing AnonymousAuthenticationToken). See SEC-610.
        if (existingAuth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                              Authentication authResult) throws IOException {
    }

    protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
    }

    protected AuthenticationEntryPoint getAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated Use constructor injection
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void setAuthenticationEntryPoint(AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    protected AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated Use constructor injection
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    protected boolean isIgnoreFailure() {
        return ignoreFailure;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @deprecated Use the constructor which takes a single AuthenticationManager parameter
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void setIgnoreFailure(boolean ignoreFailure) {
        this.ignoreFailure = ignoreFailure;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationDetailsSource(AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest,?> authenticationDetailsSource) {
        Assert.notNull(authenticationDetailsSource, "AuthenticationDetailsSource required");
        this.authenticationDetailsSource = authenticationDetailsSource;
    }

    public void setRememberMeServices(RememberMeServices rememberMeServices) {
        Assert.notNull(rememberMeServices, "rememberMeServices cannot be null");
        this.rememberMeServices = rememberMeServices;
    }

    public void setCredentialsCharset(String credentialsCharset) {
        Assert.hasText(credentialsCharset, "credentialsCharset cannot be null or empty");
        this.credentialsCharset = credentialsCharset;
    }

    protected String getCredentialsCharset(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        return credentialsCharset;
    }
}
```

Entry point:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Resource(name = "applicationEncryptor")
    StringEncryptor encryptor;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        return getUserDetails(username);
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(String username) {
        try {
            User user = null;
            user = userRepository.findByTokenID(username);

            return user;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("DataAccessException - possibly duplicate username " + username + ".");
        }
    }

}
```

Some of the details are omitted but it's basically everything that you need for your scenario.

edit: This is only for /legacy-urls/

If you want seamless access you will only have to create filter and add it in **sec** element before BASIC_AUTH_FILTER:

```
<custom-filter before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myTokenObtainingFilter" />
```

Logic in your filter should be that it continues with the chain if there is no custom header, and if there is populate authentication with token and pass it down the chain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Something that I am not sure if I understand correctly: the `<http>` configuration seems means to me that it is only for securing `/legacy-app/*` URLs.  However, for my case, I actually wants to provide both normal login and legacy-token-based-SSO, and let both of them to access same applications (hence same URLs).  In such case, should I simply add the Token Authentication Filter in the original filter chain? Or is your approach already doing what I am aiming?  Thanks